# Is there a standard name for this definition?

Tags: functions, terminology

Consider an n-ary function from a set $S$ to itself. For a specific example consider the function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by the formula $xy^2$. I define a reduction of that function to be a function where you hold zero or more variables constant. So for example, the reductions of that function are $xy^2$, $cx^2$ (where $c$ is an arbitrary real number), $px$ (where $p$ is an arbitrary non-negative number), and nullary functions $r$, where $r$ is an arbitrary real number. Is there a standard name for this definition?

Comment: Could ‘restriction of a function’ be helpful here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computer science, this concept is known as [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). Wikipedia defines this as "fixing a number of arguments to a function, producing a function of smaller aritity". This is related to the notion of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 0):

I think "restriction" would explain itself best, unless there is a more-specific term in your special case (unknown to me).

That is, if we have a function $f:X\times Y\to Z$, and consider the function $F(x)=f(x,y_o)\in Z$ for a fixed $y_o\in Y$, I'd say that $F$ is a *restriction* of $f$.

Some people might say "slice", also, I think. But "restriction" will be understood most widely among math people, currently.